# How to avoid automatic text truncation in Win32 TaskDialog

Tags: windows, winapi, truncation, taskdialog

We are using the **[TaskDialogIndirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** function to report all type of messages in our application. The problem I see with TaskDialog is that it automatically truncates *unbreakable* text with ellipsis on both sides and there seems to be no way to avoid this behavior. So for example I am unable to display a file error with the full path of the file because the path gets truncated. I even tried the **TDF_SIZE_TO_CONTENT** flag which should auto resize the dialog based on the content but it only works for slightly longer paths and truncates again.

Anyone got any ideas on this? Any workarounds?

Comment: You could put the full path in the "expanded information" section perhaps?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Let me try that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: yup, that is what I do, and it works fine. No need to waste screen space displaying the filename unless the user asks to see it.